# BCDedit -set description - не удаётся найти указанный файл

Tags: boot, windows-7, загрузка

Доброго всемм дня.
Странно, почему BCDedit при прописывании параметра /set description "bla-bla-bla" выдаёт: "не удаётся найти указанный файл."?
Или что-то делаю не так?
Дополню, cmd-шку запускал от имени АДМ

Comment: Какой неживой форум :(

Answer (score 1):

bcdedit /set {ID} description "Новое название"